# symfony2 debugging: user gets disconnected when accessing routes behind other firewall despite same context

Tags: php, symfony, debugging, http-redirect, disconnect

After some debugging, I understood that my user was disconnected from any route under a firewall where anonymous was set to false.

This is strange as it does not happen on my local computer and all was fine until now.

How to debug this further?

Please note I have specified the same context for my 2 firewalls, the publicone, and the other one where the issue happens.

My security.yml:

## app/config/security.yml

```
security:
    # La valeur de « Strategy » peut être : affirmative, unanimous ou consensus
    access_decision_manager:
        strategy: unanimous
    firewalls:
        dev:
            pattern:  ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
            security: false
        guest:
            pattern:        /(public/|$|genemu-captcha-refresh|media/cache/)
            anonymous:      true
            context:        main_auth
        main:
            http_basic: ~
            pattern:        ^/
            anonymous:      false
            provider:       main
            context:        main_auth
            switch_user: { role: ROLE_ADMIN, parameter: _switch_user_parameter }
            form_login:
                login_path: fos_user_security_login
                check_path: fos_user_security_check
                success_handler: authentication_site_handler
            logout:
                path:       fos_user_security_logout
                target:     /
            remember_me:
                key:      "%secret%"
                lifetime: 86400 #en secondes
                path:     /
                domain:   ~ # Prend la valeur par défaut du domaine courant depuis $_SERVER
            oauth:
                remember_me: true
                resource_owners:
                    facebook:           "/loginhwi/check-facebook"
                    github:             "/loginhwi/check-github"
                    google:             "/loginhwi/check-google"
                    twitter:            "/loginhwi/check-twitter"
                    linkedin:           "/loginhwi/check-linkedin"
                    flickr:             "/loginhwi/check-flickr"
                login_path:        fos_user_security_login
                check_path:        fos_user_security_check
                failure_path:      fos_user_security_login
                success_handler:  authentication_site_handler
                oauth_user_provider:
                    service: fosubuser.provider
    providers:
        main:
            id: fos_user.user_provider.username_email
    encoders:
        AppBundle\Entity\User\User: sha512
#Role hierarchy is now managed from the database
#    role_hierarchy:
#        ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN:       [ROLE_ADMIN, ROLE_ALLOWED_TO_SWITCH] #Allowed full access
    access_control:
        - { path: ^/admin, ip: 127.0.0.1, requires_channel: http, roles: ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN }
        - { path: ^/ , roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY}
```

Answer (score 0):

OK, the error came from

```
        http_basic: ~
```

in the main firewall.
I don't recall why I put it but removing it solved the issue.